# Form type, how to get the annotation error

Tags: forms, symfony, annotations, abstract-type

Do you how I can get the annotation error from my entity to display them in my twig page ?

My controller :

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
      $Sms = new Sms();
      $form = $this->createForm(new SmsType(), $Sms);

      if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if($form->isValid())
        {
          $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', true);


          return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dimi_esg_contact_success'));
        }
      }

      return $this->render('DimiEsgBundle:Home:index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

My entity class :

```
class Sms
{
  /**
   * @var integer $mobile
   *
   * @Assert\NotBlank(
   *     message="Ne peut être vide."
   * )
   * @Assert\Regex(
   *     pattern="/^(06|07)[0-9]{8}$/",
   *     match=false,
   *     message="Doit être un mobile français."
   * )
   */
  private $mobile;

//...
}
```

Thanks you all for your helping.
Best regards, Dimitri

**EDIT**

To display the error, we have to use form_error() in the twig template.

Comment: Hello Dimi, please post your twig page, my guess is that you are missing form_error().

Comment: Hooooo !! Thanks you ! I have missed the form_error()... Thanks you !

Comment: could you please add this as an answer and accept it ?